# Expectation of positive part of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a random variable $X$, does the following inequality hold?

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[\max\{X,0\}]=\max\{\mathbb{E}[X],0\}
\end{equation*}

I know that in general for a function $f(X)$ the equality does not hold. I just wondered whether it is the same for the positive part function.

Comment: no, for ex consider X is 10 wp 1/2 and -10 wp 1/2. Then the LHS is 5 but the RHS is 0

Comment: Try finding a distribution of $X$ that $\Pr (X> 0) > 0$, but $E(X) \le 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Example where the equality **does** hold:  $$\Pr[X \ge 0] = 1,$$ namely any random variable with nonnegative support.  Examples include the exponential distribution $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mathbb 1 (x \ge 0), \quad \lambda > 0.$$

Example where the equality **does not** hold:  $$X = 2Y - 1, \quad Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2).$$  Then $$\max\{X,0\} = \begin{cases} 0, & X = -1 \\ 1, & X = 1 \end{cases}$$ and $$\operatorname{E}[\max\{X,0\}] = 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2},$$ but $$\max\{\operatorname{E}[X],0\} = \max\{2\operatorname{E}[Y]-1, 0\} = \max\{2 \cdot\tfrac{1}{2} - 1, 0\} = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $$f\colon x\mapsto \max(x,0)$$ is a convex function, you have one inequality by [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):
$$
 \max(\mathbb{E}[X],0) \leq \mathbb{E}[\max(X,0)] \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
The other inequality, however, is false in general. For it to hold, the equality case of Jensen's inequality says that you need $X$ to be a constant a.s., *or* to have support in a set where $f$ is linear. *I.e., given our specific $f$, overall, you need $X\leq 0$ a.s. or $X\geq 0$ a.s. for $(\dagger)$ to be an equality.*

Comment: Equality holds if $X \leq 0$ almost surely or $X \geq 0$ almost surely or

Comment: True, I missed a case.

Answer (score 0):

RHS $\leq $ LHS and equality holds iff $X \geq 0$ almost surely or $X \leq 0$ almost surely.

For a proof just use the fact that $Y 
\geq 0$ almost surely and $EY=0$ implies $Y=0$ almost surely. [Take $Y=\max \{X ,0\}-X$ when $EX \geq 0$ and $Y=\max \{X ,0\}$ when $EX <0$].